# What can players visiting via Dodo Code do to my island in Animal Crossing New Horizons?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

In the Animal Crossing: New Horizons game for the Nintendo Switch, what can online users visiting via a Dodo Code do on my island?

I'm particularly interested in any sort of "griefing" behavior I should be aware of before I open my island to strangers. I'd like to know the risks before I share a Dodo Code on social media if I have e.g. a good turnip sell price.

It might also be helpful to know if there are differences in what visitors can do when they are considered friends or "best friends".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick up items that are dropped (not placed), pick flowers and harvest trees (which isn‘t that „bad“ bc this will grow back, since you need an axe/shovel to completely kill/steal flowers or trees and you can only use the axe or shovel when you are Best Friends with the Person.

So actually nothing that doesn‘t grow back, just make sure you don‘t have items laying around. Same goes for money trees, fence them around. 
I always walk around my island before opening with dodo code for random players, I pick up the message in the bottle and other stuff so I don‘t have to worry about something